# SimpleDateFormat Query

Tags: java

I have the following snippet

```
Date date=null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
        date= sdf.parse("2001-02-2012");
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Strangely it doesn't throw the parse exception, shouldn't it?

Comment: Is this `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`? It hasn't a 1-parameter `parse` function.

Comment: @poitroae: Yes it does - inherited from DateFormat.

Comment: Try with `sdf.setLenient(false);` - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14786257/1037210).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your input is kind of *unexpected*. The SimpleDateFormat then tries to interpret it anyway in a useful way. Thus, in your case there are `2001` days which are simply converted to weeks, months and years then. Your date is `Mon Jul 24 00:00:00 GMT 2017`. You can check this on ideone: http://ideone.com/bfgogz

To "fix" it, you can add a `sdf.setLenient(false);` to only accept input that is exactly the way you specified it.

Answer (score 2):

Acc. to docs:

```
public Date parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string**.

and

> throws `ParseException` - if the **beginning** of the specified string cannot be parsed.

See: [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse)

Answer (score 2):

It would throw `ParseException` if you parse it non leniently.  `DateFormat#setLenient(false)` it is also know **strict parsing**.

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With
>   lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs
>   that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing,
>   inputs must match this object's format.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) -

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
try{
    date = sdf.parse("2001-02-2012");
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result -

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2001-02-2012"
```

*Note: By Default `Dateformat/SimpleDateFormat` parse leniently.*